# ThreadPoolExecutor Callbacks?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I have the following code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def download_contract_history(self, **kw):
    ThreadPoolExecutor().map(lambda x: x.download_contract_history(**kw), self.instruments.values())
    print("All downloads complete.")
```

It currently prints "All downloads complete" immediately, while the actual download tasks continue asynchronously. How can I get it to print the statement after the threads actually finish?

Answer (score 0):

Being able to do other things at the same time is kind of the point. If you want to wait on completion then you need to check the returned results.

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) aren't very clear, but they do say:

> The returned iterator raises a `concurrent.futures.TimeoutError` if
>   `__next__()` is called and the result isn’t available after timeout seconds

So it seems that `map` returns a result iterator, and the results are actual results not futures, so you could do:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def download_contract_history(self, **kw):
    results = list(
        ThreadPoolExecutor().map(
            lambda x: x.download_contract_history(**kw),
            self.instruments.values()
        )
    )
    print("All downloads complete.")
```